# What is exactly a method specification in Java

Tags: java, methods, specifications

One of my friends who also studying Java, asked me: "What is the difference between method specification and method signature in Java?"

I know what is method signature, it is a method name and its parameters - `methodName(int n, String str)` e.g.

But what is exactly a method specification in Java?

All what I found in Internet - is a [pdf-file](http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tmertz/Java/031usingmethods/04methodspecifications.pdf) only. There is following information about method specification:

1. The name of the package and class in which the method is defined.
2. The method identifier to be used to call it.
3. Its parameters; i.e. what data you must pass it as arguments.
4. What it does and its return value, if any.
5. Whether it is an instance or a class method

So, as I understand, the method specification includes package name (`package com.site.progect` e.g.), method signature (`methodName(int n, String str)`), access specificators (`private`, `protected`, default or `public`), type of return value, `static` identificator (if the method is static and does not belong to instance).

Does a method specification includes the name of class, where our method wad defined? Does it includes an indication to the throwing of exception, which goes after the method signature (`... throws Exception()`)? Does it includes developers comment about what the method does?

Comment: Depends on the implementation scenario...

Comment: `4. What it does` is the important distinction. The specification (which is not in code, but in words) describes what the method should be doing. The method signature is only the part the compiler needs.

Comment: @Thilo - this informaton must be in comment?

Comment: @VitaliyTretyakov A *Javadoc* would be good, yes. But depending on the case, there may be much more specification elsewhere (in a book, whitepaper, etc).

Answer (score 2):

There might be a confusion about two different concepts.

1. One is a (natural language) description of what a method *ought to* be. It describes in English (or any other language) what the goals of the method are, possibly (but not necessarily) its parameters and return values.
2. The second one is a phrase used in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/index.html) exactly once [in an example about abstract classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1) but never formally defined.

Usage #2 *seems* to basically refer to a method signature together with the return type of the method.

In other words while `methodName(int n, String str)` is the signature of a method, one possible "method specification" would be `Object methodName(int n, String str)` according to meaning #2.

Answer (score 1):

The method specification may be seen as the documentation for the method.
You can write it like this:

```
/**
 * Method - Description of the method
 * @param int n - description of parameter
 * @param String str - description of parameter
 * @return int - description of the return value
 **/
int methodName(int n, String str)
{
 ...
}
```

This syntax will be used to generate javadoc. You can see more details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html)